# Why None is returned during recursion when i try to return count?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
def myfun1(count):
    count += 1
    if count == 10:
        return count
    print(count)
    myfun1(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(myfun1(0))
```

I want to return the count and terminate the recursion when count == 10.
The above code returns None when count == 10. Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: I've written a statement to return count. Where is the value in count being returned?

Comment: You should replace `myfun1(count)` by `return myfun1(count)`. Otherwise you completely ignore and discard the returned value of the recursive call, and don't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruction `myfun1(count)` performs a recursive call but you don't do anything of the value returned by this call.  You need to return a value when you reach the end of your function.  Otherwise, when the end of the function is reached, you have an implicit `return None` statement.

So if you want to return the result of your recursive call, do something like that:

```py
def myfun1(count):
    count += 1
    if count == 10:
        return count
    print(count)
    result = myfun1(count)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(myfun1(0))
```

Generally speaking when a function (recursive or not) is supposed to return something that it computed, make sure that it ends with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First you need Else to return a different value in return, instead you will always return 10 in your recursion

```
def myFun1(count):
   count += 1
   if count == 10:
       return count
    else: 
       return count
```

and you have refactore some points of your function to make the recursion, call it again

```
def myFun1(count):
   count += 1
   if count == 10:
       return count
   else:
      count_res = myFun1(count)
      return count_res
```

and you have just call the function

if **name** == '**main**':
print(myFun1(0))